# Convert a python file to a library

Tags: java, python, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to convert a python file into a library which can be reused by other applications that are written in Java or Python. I am planning to convert the .py file into a library which can be used as a service or API later on using AWS Lambda. Has anyone worked on something similar and have some pointers on how it could be implemented?

Comment: An **AWS Lambda** function can be invoked via **AWS API Gateway**. There is no need to convert the code into a "library" since the Lambda function can directly run your Python code. Take a look at some YouTube videos that combine both of those services.

Comment: This is asking about a python function and has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 2):

Pls have a look and try at this article: how to create python library.
They are writing very clear and in details I think you can create your library in 4 hours :)

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f

Comment: But I need to create it only once. Such that the library could be reused by other applications written in Java/ Python. So I need to convert it to a service / API which anyone would be able to use

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your python file into an API for anyone to use the easiest way is to use Flask.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

With a basic structure like this you can run your server/API and when you query http://127.0.0.1:5000/ you'd get "Hello World" response.

You can find Flask documentation here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

And since you want to use AWS Lambda moving forward here is a guide how to create an API using Flask and AWS Lambda: https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb